# My php math is not working

Tags: php, math, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a simple division with 2 numbers from my array like this.

here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [day] => 2013-04-06
            [hour] => 06
            [hits] => 4
            [executetime] => 10.0000
        )

)
```

I am then dividing them like this:

//### EDIT ###//

```
$thisHour = date("H", time());
$thisDate = date("Y-m-d", time());

$total_time = 2.5000;

$moveStats = $memcache->get('moveStats');

foreach ($moveStats as $k => $v) {
    $moveStats[$k]['hits']=$moveStats[$k]['hits']+1; // UPDATING THE HITS

    $moveStats[$k]['executetime'] += $total_time;
    $moveStats[$k]['executetime'] = number_format($moveStats[$k]['executetime'] / (++$moveStats[$k]['hits']),4,'.','');
}

$memcache->set('moveStats', $moveStats);
```

This strangly enough gives me this number: 1.75!

I guess it should be 2.5?

What am I doing wrong. please help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why don't you use the `++` and `+=` [assignment operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) for readability?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
    $moveStats[$k]['executetime']=$moveStats[$k]['executetime']+$total_time;
```

instand of

```
   $moveStats[$k]['executetime']+$total_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line has no assignment:

```
$moveStats[$k]['executetime']+$total_time;
```

Also, what value does $total_time contain?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to:

```
$total_time = 2.5000;
foreach ($moveStats as $k => $v) {
    $moveStats[$k]['executetime'] += $total_time;
    echo $moveStats[$k]['executetime'] / (++$moveStats[$k]['hits']);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your example, and when just doing so it works, but when I try to insert into the array again it does what it always  have done. Look at my edited example at the top.